# How to record voice on flutter desktop platform？

Tags: flutter, record, desktop, voice

I want to record voice on flutter desktop platform.

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1526], locale zh-CN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.5)
[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.3)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the available flutter packages? If not, then try with [flutter_desktop_audio_recorder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_desktop_audio_recorder)   or [record](https://pub.dev/packages/record). Both of them supports Windows.

Please follow the readme section for implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Use [record](https://pub.dev/packages/record) package,

Step 1: Declare variable for storing audio recording data:

```
  int recordDuration = 0;
  Timer? _timer;
  final _audioRecorder = Record();
  StreamSubscription<RecordState>? _recordSub;
  RecordState recordState = RecordState.stop;
  String? audioPath;
  bool? isRecording;
  String? minutes = "00";
  String? seconds = "00";
```

Step 2: Create initiate method:

```
initRecorder() async {
    _recordSub = _audioRecorder.onStateChanged().listen((recordStateThis) {
      recordState = recordStateThis;
    });
    audioPath = null;
    isRecorderInitialized = true;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Step 3: Create methods for starting, stopping, resuming, pausing recording:

```
  Future<void> _start() async {
    try {
      if (await _audioRecorder.hasPermission()) {
        final isSupported = await _audioRecorder.isEncoderSupported(
          AudioEncoder.aacLc,
        );
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('${AudioEncoder.aacLc.name} supported: $isSupported');
        }
        // isRecording = await _audioRecorder.isRecording();
        await _audioRecorder.start();
        recordDuration = 0;
        _startTimer();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

  Future<void> _stop() async {
    _timer?.cancel();
    recordDuration = 0;
    final path = await _audioRecorder.stop();
    if (path != null) {
      onStop(path);
    }
  }


  Future<void> _pause() async {
    _timer?.cancel();
    await _audioRecorder.pause();
  }

  Future<void> _resume() async {
    _startTimer();
    await _audioRecorder.resume();
  }
```

Step 4: Declare method for starting timer:

```
  void _startTimer() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      recordDuration++;
      minutes = _formatNumber(recordDuration ~/ 60);
      seconds = _formatNumber(recordDuration % 60);
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  String _formatNumber(int number) {
    String numberStr = number.toString();
    if (number < 10) {
      numberStr = '0$numberStr';
    }

    return numberStr;
  }
```

Step 5: Dispose recorder at end:

```
  disposeRecorder() {
    _timer?.cancel();
    _recordSub?.cancel();
    _audioRecorder.dispose();
    isRecorderInitialized = false;
    debugPrint("Dispose Success");
  }
```

Use these methods in your ui.