# PlatformException on starting recorder with flutter_sound

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code:

```
import 'package:audio_session/audio_session.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sound/flutter_sound.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sound_platform_interface/flutter_sound_recorder_platform_interface.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class MicTest {

  static FlutterSoundRecorder? _mRecorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();

  static Codec _codec = Codec.aacMP4;

  static const theSource = AudioSource.microphone;

  static void startRecorder() async {
    await _mRecorder!.openRecorder();
    final session = await AudioSession.instance;
    await session.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration(
      avAudioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategory.playAndRecord,
      avAudioSessionCategoryOptions:
      AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth |
      AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker,
      avAudioSessionMode: AVAudioSessionMode.spokenAudio,
      avAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy:
      AVAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicy.defaultPolicy,
      avAudioSessionSetActiveOptions: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptions.none,
      androidAudioAttributes: const AndroidAudioAttributes(
        contentType: AndroidAudioContentType.speech,
        flags: AndroidAudioFlags.none,
        usage: AndroidAudioUsage.voiceCommunication,
      ),
      androidAudioFocusGainType: AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gain,
      androidWillPauseWhenDucked: true,
    ));
    print("initialized");
    String _mPath = 'tau_file.mp4';
    var tempPath = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    _mPath = tempPath.path + "/" + _mPath;
    _mRecorder!
        .startRecorder(
      toFile: _mPath,
      codec: _codec,
      audioSource: theSource,
    )
    .then((value) {
      //setState(() {});
    });
  }

  static void stopRecorder() async {
    await _mRecorder!.stopRecorder().then((value) {
      // setState(() {
      //   //var url = value;
      //   _mplaybackReady = true;
      // });
    });
  }
}
```

When I call MicTest.startRecorder() I get:

```
I/flutter ( 6616): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #0   new FlutterSoundRecorder (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:140:13)
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #1   MicrophoneUtils._mRecorder (package:myapp/utils/mic_test.dart:9:45)
I/flutter ( 6616): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6616): │  ctor: FlutterSoundRecorder()
I/flutter ( 6616): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #0   FlutterSoundRecorder.openRecorder (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:372:13)
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #1   MicrophoneUtils.startRecorder (package:myapp/utils/mic_test.dart:16:23)
I/flutter ( 6616): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6616): │  FS:---> openAudioSession 
I/flutter ( 6616): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #0   FlutterSoundRecorder._openAudioSession (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:381:13)
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #1   FlutterSoundRecorder.openRecorder.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:374:17)
I/flutter ( 6616): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6616): │  ---> openAudioSession
I/flutter ( 6616): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #0   FlutterSoundRecorder._openAudioSession (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:396:17)
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #1   FlutterSoundRecorder.openRecorder.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:374:17)
I/flutter ( 6616): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6616): │  Resetting flutter_sound Recorder Plugin
I/flutter ( 6616): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
E/MediaRecorder( 6616): resume called in an invalid state: 1
E/MediaRecorder( 6616): stop called in an invalid state: 1
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:430)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.success(MethodChannel.java:267)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at com.dooboolab.fluttersound.FlutterSoundManager.resetPlugin(FlutterSoundManager.java:88)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at com.dooboolab.fluttersound.FlutterSoundRecorderManager.onMethodCall(FlutterSoundRecorderManager.java:70)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/MethodChannel#com.dooboolab.flutter_sound_recorder( 6616):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/DartMessenger( 6616): Uncaught exception in binary message listener
E/DartMessenger( 6616): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted
E/DartMessenger( 6616):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$Reply.reply(DartMessenger.java:430)
E/DartMessenger( 6616):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:282)
E/DartMessenger( 6616):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/DartMessenger( 6616):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/DartMessenger( 6616):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/DartMessenger( 6616):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/DartMessenger( 6616):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/DartMessenger( 6616):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/DartMessenger( 6616):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/DartMessenger( 6616):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/DartMessenger( 6616):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/DartMessenger( 6616):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
I/flutter ( 6616): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #0   FlutterSoundRecorder.openRecorderCompleted (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:171:13)
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #1   MethodChannelFlutterSoundRecorder.channelMethodCallHandler (package:flutter_sound_platform_interface/method_channel_flutter_sound_recorder.dart:98:22)
I/flutter ( 6616): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6616): │  ---> openRecorderCompleted: true
I/flutter ( 6616): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #0   FlutterSoundRecorder.openRecorderCompleted (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:182:13)
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #1   MethodChannelFlutterSoundRecorder.channelMethodCallHandler (package:flutter_sound_platform_interface/method_channel_flutter_sound_recorder.dart:98:22)
I/flutter ( 6616): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6616): │  <--- openRecorderCompleted: true
I/flutter ( 6616): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #0   FlutterSoundRecorder._openAudioSession (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:412:13)
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #1   <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 6616): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6616): │  <--- openAudioSession
I/flutter ( 6616): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #0   FlutterSoundRecorder.openRecorder (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:376:13)
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #1   <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter ( 6616): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6616): │  FS:<--- openAudioSession 
I/flutter ( 6616): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): initialized
I/flutter ( 6616): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #0   FlutterSoundRecorder.startRecorder (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:590:13)
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #1   MicrophoneUtils.startRecorder (package:myapp/utils/mic_test.dart:40:10)
I/flutter ( 6616): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6616): │  FS:---> startRecorder 
I/flutter ( 6616): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #0   FlutterSoundRecorder._startRecorder (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:614:13)
I/flutter ( 6616): │ #1   FlutterSoundRecorder.startRecorder.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:592:13)
I/flutter ( 6616): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6616): │  FS:---> _startRecorder.
I/flutter ( 6616): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
E/flutter ( 6616): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(startRecorder, startRecorder, Failure to start recorder, null)
E/flutter ( 6616): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter ( 6616): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter ( 6616): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6616): #2      FlutterSoundRecorder._startRecorder (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:671:7)
E/flutter ( 6616): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6616): #3      FlutterSoundRecorder.startRecorder.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:592:7)
E/flutter ( 6616): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6616): #4      BasicLock.synchronized (package:synchronized/src/basic_lock.dart:33:16)
E/flutter ( 6616): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6616): #5      FlutterSoundRecorder.startRecorder (package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart:591:5)
E/flutter ( 6616): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6616):
```

I've just started using flutter_sound, so I think the problem is in my code. Could anyone say how to fix this problem?

Comment: Permission Error , Add Permission Properly

Comment: have you fixed this, if yes please share it.

Comment: @Akhil No, I decided to use another library. But I think (am almost sure) that the problem was in permissions.

Comment: which package you used

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to just import

```
import 'package:flutter_sound/public/flutter_sound_recorder.dart';
```

instead of

```
import 'package:flutter_sound/flutter_sound.dart';
```

from the same **flutter_sound** package.

However, I suggest you to use another package for recording audio because **flutter_sound** seems like an abandoned package.

My choice for now is this [record](https://pub.dev/packages/record) package.

Here is [how to implement record package with ease](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77285037/12110705).